# Python- How to fix failed testcase on a has repeat function?

Tags: python-3.x, indexing, conditional-statements

I've built a function that checks for repeats of a specific number in a list named xs. V is the number to check for repeats of. It needs to return True if there are more than one occurrences of the number and if there are none, it needs to return False.

I'm failing one test case which is input xs=[1,2,1] v=1, this function needs to return True, but my code is making it False. Can you see where I went wrong?

Here is my current code:

```
def has_repeat(xs, v):
    count=0
    for num in range(len(xs)):
        if num == v:
            count+=1
    if count>1:
       return True
    else:
       return False
```

Comment: is `for num in range(len(xs))` not just returning a list like `[0, 1, 2]` (or `[1, 2, 3]`, not sure which) as you're getting a range from 0 to the length of xs which is 3?

This means in turn your check is iterating `[0, 1, 2]` and checking it against `v`, of which it will only hit `num == v` once

Comment: If it's only hitting it once, how do I get it to keep going? I thought by using range(len()) it would go through the whole list.

Comment: No you need to do `for num in xs` I think, let me check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're actually iterating over the range of the length of the list, not the items in the list.

The `range` function returns a list of numbers from 0 (by default) to the number you provide, in this case 3 (not inclusive). See [Python documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range)

As an example if you try:

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
print(range(len(l)))
```

It will print out `[0, 1, 2]`

What you should do is instead of

```
for num in range(len(xs))
```

do

```
for num in xs:
```

You can try it out on PyFiddle [here](http://pythonfiddle.com/kg123-stackoverflow/)

As an added tasty bonus, you  could change this to use the `.count` method on your list of items to check how many occurrences of that number are in the list, removing the need to iterate the list at all, like so:

```
count = xs.count(v)
```